# While-loop over lines from variable in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, heredoc, herestring

Assume a file `file` with multiple lines.

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz
```

Assume further that I wish to loop through each line with a while-loop.

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
$   echo $line
$   # do stuff
$ done < file
foo
bar
baz
```

Finally, please assume that I wish to pass lines stored in a variable rather than lines stored in a file. How can I loop through lines that are saved as a variable without receiving the below error?

```
$ MY_VAR=$(cat file)
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
$   echo $line
$   # do stuff
$ done < $(echo "$MY_VAR")
bash: $(echo "$MY_VAR"): ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: `echo $line` is not the same as `echo "$line"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Also, all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or OS, whereas names with lowercase characters are guaranteed not to conflict with system operation. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options:

- A herestring (note that this is a non-POSIX extension): `done <<<"$MY_VAR"`
- A heredoc (POSIX-compliant, will work with `/bin/sh`):

  ```
  done <<EOF
  $MY_VAR
  EOF
  ```
- A process substitution (also a non-POSIX extension, but using `printf` rather than `echo` makes it more predictable across shells that support it; see the APPLICATION USAGE note in the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)): `done < <(printf '%s\n' "$MY_VAR")`

---

Note that the first two options will (in bash) create a temporary file on disk with the variable's contents, whereas the last one uses a FIFO.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations as well as the useful comments above. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`<` needs to be followed by a filename. You can use a here-string:

```
done <<< "$MY_VAR"
```

or process substitution:

```
done < <(echo "$MY_VAR")
```